# Dimension too large after exporting box plot with matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

When exporting a box plot with `matlab2tikz` I get no errors, but when running pdflatex I get a `"dimension too large"` error. This only happens with box plots. Still the box plot shows up as it should, except only x labels ('A' , 'B' etc) are missing.

Plots in Matlab are generated by

```
matlab2tikz( 'myfile.tex', 'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth' );
```

Plots in LaTeX are generated by

```
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{5cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{5cm}
\input{myfile.tex}
```

Any ideas?

Here is the content of `myfile.tex`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
unbounded coords=jump,
clip=false,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=1.5,
xtick={\empty},
ymin=-0.906787341211142,
ymax=1.91353502249058
]
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1.22705846866506\\
1 1.78533855141323\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 -0.778590870133791\\
1 -0.1615124881432\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.9625 1.78533855141323\\
1.0375 1.78533855141323\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.9625 -0.778590870133791\\
1.0375 -0.778590870133791\\
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.925 -0.1615124881432\\
0.925 1.22705846866506\\
1.075 1.22705846866506\\
1.075 -0.1615124881432\\
0.925 -0.1615124881432\\
};
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.925 0.232038283285484\\
1.075 0.232038283285484\\
};
\node[above, inner sep=0mm, text=black]
at (axis cs:216.829133858268, -13.9889763779528, 0) {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code generated by `matlab2tikz`?

Comment: The problem is that final `\node` command: Your axis only goes from x=0.5 to 1.5, but the node is positioned at x=216.8, which is waaaay over to the right. Where is the node supposed to go? Also, maybe you're better served with using the `boxplot` functionality that's been introduced in PGFPlots recently (see [Boxplots in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115210/boxplot-in-latex))

Comment: Take also a look if the error still persists once you have solved the problem raised by @Jake to the number of digits after the coma for your y-axis. I remember to have already crossed such a problem with the `pgfplots` package. See this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120262/31058) for more details.

Comment: exactly @LudovicC.
it´s definitely useful to limit the number of digits after the comma in _gnuplot_ via `set format "% .5f"`, as for example you might get pseudo-zero values like `1e-14` which pgf cannot handle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that final `\node` command: Your axis only goes from `x=0.5` to `1.5`, but the node is positioned at `x=216.8`, which is waaaay over to the right. Also, maybe you're better served with using the boxplot functionality that's been introduced in PGFPlots recently (see [Boxplots in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115210/boxplot-in-latex))